# Show that a reparametrization of a parametrized curve is regular iff that curve is regular

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

Show that a reparametrization of $\widetilde{c}$ of a parametrized curve $c$ is regular if and only if $c$ is regular.

How do I go about answering this question? I think it's essentially asking me to show that a reparametrization of a regular curve is regular. I believe $c$ is regular if $c^{'}$ ≠ 0.

(Sorry if my formatting is bad. I'm new and I'm trying to follow a MathJax tutorial)